# How to convert from timestamp to date in this kind of PHP?

Tags: php

I am not a professional web developer, and my PHP is bad. I want to convert from timestamp to a readable date format `(d.m, h:i:s)`.

This is the whole paragraph:

```
<p><b>Last Visit:</b>' . $user['last_online']. '</p>
```

And this is what I want to convert to a date format:

```
' . $user['last_online']. '
```

Comment: What is that status of this question? You have three answers that should resolve the issue you've described.

Comment: No answers has helped. Still stuck.

Comment: Update your question with how `<p><b>Last Visit:</b>' . $user['last_online']. '</p>` is currently being used and what `$user['last_online']` has stored in it.

Answer (score 2):

Per the `date` entry in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

> Returns a string formatted according to the given format string using the given integer timestamp or the current time if no timestamp is given. In other words, timestamp is optional and defaults to the value of time().

So if you give the timestamp as the second parameter of the function it will format that timestamp.

So

```
'<p><b>Last Visit:</b>' . date('d.m, h:i:s', $user['last_online']). '</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 echo date("d.m h:i:s", strtotime($user["last_online"]);
```

Remove the echo because your inside a php.

```
 <p style="word-wrap:break-word;">'.clean($user['motto']).'<BR><BR><b>Last Visit:</b><br>'.date("d.m h:i:s", strtotime($user["last_online"]).'</p>
```

Comment: pretty sure I got that edit right. You missed a few things. Double check it.

Comment: It didn't work. Even when I put the apostrophes there.

Comment: then again, I don't think so. That should probably read as `echo date("d.m h:i:s", strtotime($user['last_online']);` you originally had `echo date('d.m h:i:s, strtotime($user['last_online');`

Comment: I think the `$user['last_online']` is a timestamp already.

Comment: Yes. I've got my apostrophies bad. Lol. Sorry for that.

Comment: *aye*, no problemo ;-)

Comment: Im on phone right now. It's hard to code. :D

Comment: But it doesn't work.

Comment: The echo shows up as the same color (grey) as the HTML. This is in Notepad ++.

Comment: The echo shows up? Are you in a PHP block and/or is this a PHP file?

Comment: It's a PHP file, as it's saved as .php. But it's alot of HTML in it. It's supposed to echo a <div> after getting info from the database.

Comment: You must enclose that in php tag `<?php echo date("d.m h:i:s", strtotime(youdate); ?>` if you are in HTML file

Comment: It's not an HTML file. It still shows up like Notepad reads it as HTML......

Comment: So does it work when you echoed it? Is the extension of your file is .php?

Comment: What is your editor and your file extension?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7pP4VMtR Check out line 54-55

Comment: I see. Change my single quotes to double quotes.\

Comment: It still doesn't work... :/

Answer (score 0):

Or the object oriented way:

```php
$date = new DateTime($user['last_online']);
print $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

By using the `DateTime` object you can specify timezones, which is often useful:

```php
$date = new DateTime($user['last_online'], DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
print $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The first two examples are for string dates. If, as you say, your value is a timestamp you can prefix the value with an `@`:

```php
$date = new DateTime(sprintf('@%d', $user['last_online']));
```

Comment: I don't know how or where to set this up.